# How to add gradients to text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, linear-gradients, radial-gradients, gradient

Currently I'm working on a little project and want to know how to add gradient to text using **JavaScript** like in CSS.

Comment: Take a look here: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=text%20gradient&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything

Comment: Have you already tried something on you own to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding gradient to text using JS is as same as adding it using CSS

According to CSS written on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) it's possible to add in JS using this code

```
const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
h1.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#eee, red)';
h1.style.webkitBackgroundClip = 'text';  
h1.style.webkitTextFillColor = 'transparent';
```